# Adjective meaning "with good visibility?"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Example:

> There was a bright moon in the sky. If it weren't for the fog, the
>   streets would have looked incredibly [...].

I can't think of the right adjetive (aside of *clear*).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't think there is such a word. More importantly, though, that's a highly unnatural way of describing the scenery to begin with. If it's foggy, there _isn't_ a bright moon in the sky, 'cause a bright moon in the sky means that the moon is bright when you look at it from earth. When there's a fog, you can't see the moon at all. I'd say something like, “High above, the moon shone out, but the streets of the city where cloaked in a thick fog so you couldn't see ten feet ahead of you on the ground”—that's a more natural way of looking at things.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: +1. Why can't you post this as an answer?

Comment: Please note that he is looking for a VERB ... should the OP not read "adjective" ? Why has nobody picked that up?

Comment: @NamSandStorm Oh, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: " If it weren't for the fog, the streets would have" shown with incredible **clarity**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sharp* might be the word you are looking for. You might also omit *incredibly* and use *clearly* *outlined*.